# spark - SparkContext and SqlContext - lifecycle and threadsafty

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am developing rest services top of spark which takes user query as input, formulate spark sql and execute it on spark cluster. Here's what my assumption with JavaSparkContext and JavaSqlContext: 
1) They both threadsafe
2) I can reuse single instance throughout application(Context!)

Based on this I initialize only one instance of these variables during application startup and then tries to reuse them for all incoming request.

I can fire request and get results as expected but what I found recently is my application dies if it's been idle for several minutes with following exception. 
`11:49:50.475 [spark-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] ERROR o.a.s.s.c.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend- Application has been killed. Reason: Master removed our application: FAILED

11:49:50.477 [spark-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] ERROR o.a.s.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl- Exiting due to error from cluster scheduler: Master removed our application: FAILED`

So am I wrong with any of my assumption that led me to this issue or wrong with design in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct. Actually you can only run one `SparkContext` per JVM.

Comment: Thanks.. things are much better now since I realized I need to be on certain network in order to run  against cluster

Answer (score 0):

Error I was getting was a Network Error. Our company cluster rejects connection over VPN